# What are the correct current directions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, electronics

> **i have a problem in my text book asking me to find the equivalent resistance of this circuit  :**

[image]

---

***so i used kirchhoff's first law and drew some abitritary current directions :***

[image]

***the two 6 ohm resistors are in parallel and the two 4 ohm resistors are also in parallel so we end up with two 2 ohm resistors on the top side and 3 ohm resistor and 1 ohm resistor on the bottom side so $$R_\text{eq} = { 4\over 2} = 2ohm$$ which is the correct answer according to my text box***

> ***then i  said to my self if current direction does not matter why do not i draw new current directions and i still should be able to get the same result***

[image]

---

***unfortunately by following the new current directions i end up with totally different result $$R_\text{eq} = { 42\over 13} ohm$$ and that's not supposed to happen i should be getting the same result but with negative sign 
i am not sure what went wrong***

Comment: You can use symmetry or equipotential point to solve it

Comment: Forget about current directions and just concentrate on resistors in parallel and series.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: @Farcher i cannot see parallel nor series resistors,  it's so complex to be solved this way.

Comment: @John Rennie , I did not ask for answer I already know the correct answer which is 2 according to the textbook but I need to know why the second drawing of current directions gives me different answer  ,I only asked for hints.

Comment: @AmirWG So how are the two $4\,\Omega$ connected?

Comment: @Farcher according to the first pic they are connected in parallel, and according to the second pic they look like if they are connected in series correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Farcher also I do not really understand how you are asking me to forget about current directions,  you cannot really tell anything without them.

Comment: @AmirWG Just because you **arbitrarily** draw in some arrows on a diagram to represent currents whose direction is not known does not change the fact that two resistors are connected in parallel!

Comment: @Farcher I can respect that they are arbitrary drawn,  but how did you conclude that that the two 4ohm resistor are the ones connected in parallel , two parallel resistors always connect at one point so the 0ohm wire and the 4ohm resistor can also be connected in parallel  and the real current directions are unknown after all.

Comment: @AmirWG Each end of one resistor is connected to an end of the other resistor.  The line at the bottom left is a distractor so as not to give the impression that the resistors are in parallel.

Comment: AmirWG, it might be that you're unaware of the fact that two circuit nodes connected by an ideal wire *are the same node*. In other words, the wire in the left bottom corner connecting terminals of the two 4 ohm resistors can be 'shrunk to zero length' without changing the circuit. It should then be clear that th two 4 ohm resistors are in parallel just as @Farcher has pointed out.

Comment: @Hal Hollis  sorry for late response ,  if i understood everyone correctly  if i remove the empty wires then the ciircuit can look like this right ? https://ibb.co/Ydz4K6X, i think that would not give the correct answer , am i doing something wrong again ?

Comment: @Hal Hollis You might have also meant something like this : https://ibb.co/99w9T0w

Comment: AmirWG, neither diagram is correct. It's not that you *remove* the wires, it's that you 'shrink them', i.e., you bring the two endpoints together.

Comment: @Hal Hollis can you illustrate that using a simple picture (it does not need to be perfect) i just cannot imagine it.

Comment: @Hal Hollis i mean if i try to bring end points of the empty wire togther then the two 4 ohm wires will collapse into each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in response to a point I was making in the comments - that point being that two connections joined by an ideal wire are the same electrical node which means the wire can be 'shrunk to zero length' without changing the circuit.

> can you illustrate that using a simple picture (it does not need to be
>   perfect) i just cannot imagine it
>
> i mean if i try to bring end points of the empty wire togther then the
>   two 4 ohm wires will collapse into each other

Just take the ends of the wire and 'push' them together like so ...

[image]

Comment: oh i get it now , i had one last question and i am sorry for asking alot of questions , what would be the case if we had another resistor instead of the empty wire ?

Comment: @AmirWG, that would make a $\Delta$ connection of resistors which is neither series nor parallel. One can [convert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform#Basic_Y-%CE%94_transformation) that to a $Y$ connection to make solving the problem easier.

Comment: great info , thanks alot for your time.